# Logging not displaying debug level when level is set by dictConfig

Tags: python, logging

**EDIT**: I found the issue, but I am not totally sure why it does what it does.

The issue is with `LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers']['default']['level']`. If I remove that key, then I get the desired functionality, but I dont know why it isnt overwritten by the `my_package.module.logger` logger. An explanation of this would be appreciated.

---

I am attempting to create a logging module for a package I am creating, but I don't really understand the python `logging` config dictionaries, and consequently, I cannot fix an issue I am having, where the level of the logger **should** be printing debug messages, but is not. I have the following structure:

```
my_package
    |
    |-----__init__.py
    |-----module
    |       |
    |       |-----__init__.py
    |       |-----logger.py
    |       |-----run_me.py
```

`logger.py` looks like this:

```
import logging
import logging.config

LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout',  # Default is stderr
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {  # root logger
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': False
        },
        'my_package.module.logger': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        },
        '__main__': {  # if __name__ == '__main__'
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
        },
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.warning('Configured for Warnings')
log.debug('Configured for Debug')
log.info('Configured for Info')
```

and here is `run_me.py`

```
import my_package.module.logger
```

If I run `logger.py` directly, I get the expected output

```
> TIME [WARNING] __main__: Configured for Warnings
> TIME [INFO] __main__: Configured for Info
```

But if I run `run_me.py`, I do not seem to get the expected output - the Debug level info is missing:

```
> TIME [WARNING] my_package.module.logger: Configured for Warnings
> TIME [INFO] my_package.module.logger: Configured for Info
```

The issue persists if I change the logger name in `LOGGING_CONFIG` from `my_package.module.logger` to `my_package.module`, which I assume should capture anything within the module directory.

If I remove the `__main__` logger from the config dictionary, I also get expected behaviour when running `logger.py` directly - it only shows the warning output.

Why is the debug level not appearing, despite it being explicitely set?

Answer (score 0):

The handler's level is set to INFO, it will not print any DEBUG messages.

```
'handlers': {
    'default': {
        'level': 'INFO', <-------- here
```

Comment: So the handler configs override individual logger configs? Handlers have higher priority? Just trying to understand the answer. I can see THAT its the solution, but not WHY its the solution.

Comment: Both loggers and handlers have their levels (thresholds). A message travels from a logger through one or more handlers to its destination and must satisfy the level at each step. Imagine a single logger with one stream handler configured to print each message and one email (SMTP) handler to send emails to admin with critical errors only. Python logging can be customized really a lot to match almost every possible use-case. Refer to the logging tutorial and maybe also the cookbook at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/index.html

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with that format you used, I am using the below format and it always works for me:

```
logging.basicConfig(
     filename = 'c:\\logs\\XXXX.log',
     level = logging.DEBUG,
     format = '[XXX] %(levelname)-7.7s %(message)s'# )
```

Comment: The format I am using is for configDict, which in python 3.6+, is the preferred way of setting a logging config, as far as I understand. But I am not really sure about a lot of the logging functionality!